# Is there any possibility in selenium to create instance for already opened FF browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following challenge in my application.

as soon as the application starts it will open a FF browser automatically using C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

Now i want to create an instance to the opened FF window using selenium and continue further.

```
WebDriver webDriver = null; 
try { 
   URL uri = new URL("localhost:7055/hub"); 
   webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, DesiredCapabilities.firefox()); 
   System.out.println("Executed on remote driver"); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
   webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
   System.out.println("Executed on New FireFox driver"); 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please check this link how to ask a clear question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: below is the code snippet tried using remote webdriver 


WebDriver webDriver = null;

try
{
URL uri = new URL("http://localhost:7055/hub");
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
System.out.println("Executed on remote driver");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
System.out.println("Executed on New FireFox driver");
}

Comment: Do not comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit your post, instead.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Allow webdriver to attach to a running browser](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18) :

```
I'm going to make a call on this one: it's a browser specific feature, and not something
that we can implement in a general way. With IE, it's possible to iterate over the
open windows in the OS and find the right IE process to attach to.

Firefox and Chrome, OTOH, need to be started in a specific mode and configuration,
which means that just attaching to a running instance isn't technically possible.

Closing as "not feasible" here as this is a browser specific feature.
```

It is not possible to attach selenium to already opened firefox browser instance.